# Onclick goto url and content Classname change

Tags: javascript, html, css

Iam working on Mobile only website when i click red in index page it show go to color.html and change its content classname using its id. When i click its going to the page but not changing classname. Please give me a solution

```
 Index.html:
 <script type="text/javascript">  
  function redActive(){
   document.getElementById("red").className = "red active";
  }
  function blueActive(){
   document.getElementById("blue").className = "blue active";
  }
  function greenActive(){
   document.getElementById("green").className = "green active";
  }
</script>

<div class="navi">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="color.html" onclick="redActive();">Red</a></li>
      <li><a href="color.html" onclick="blueActive();">Blue</a></li>
      <li><a href="color.html" onclick="greenActive();">Green</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

color.html:
<div id="red" class="red"></div>
<div id="blue" class="blue"></div>
<div id="green" class="green"></div>

.red.active, .blue.active, .green.active {
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because JavaScript in `index.html` can't change className in `color.html`

Try this:

Index.html

```
<div class="navi">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="color.html?c=red" onclick="redActive();">Red</a></li>
      <li><a href="color.html?c=blue" onclick="blueActive();">Blue</a></li>
      <li><a href="color.html?c=green" onclick="greenActive();">Green</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

color.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  window.onload = function(){
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var cid= query.split("=")[1];
    document.getElementById(cid).className = cid + " active";
  }
</script>

<div id="red" class="red"></div>
<div id="blue" class="blue"></div>
<div id="green" class="green"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, is there any way to remove "active" from others during adding to this one